# Aggregate parts of a column in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a matrix like this one:

```
A = [[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0],
     [ 6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0, 10.0],
     [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
     [16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]]
```

And i want to aggregate parts of the matrix. For example the mean of **6 [1][0]** and **11 [2][0]**.
My intuitiv idea was doing it like this: `np.mean(A[1:2][0])`. But this doesn't work.

How can I aggregate intervals of a matrix?

Comment: You mean `A[1:3, 0].mean()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use here Numpy to convert in in Numpy array

```
A = [[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0],
     [ 6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0, 10.0],
     [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
     [16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]]

import numpy as np
slice = np.array(A)[1:3,0]
mean = np.mean(slice)
```

In this example, we use the slicing notation A[1:3, 0] to select rows 1 to 2 (exclusive) and column 0 of matrix A. This creates a 1D array [6.0, 11.0], and then we calculate the mean using np.mean(), which gives us the result of 8.5.

Remember that when slicing arrays, the range is exclusive for the end index. So 1:3 selects rows 1 and 2, but not 3. Similarly, 0 selects only column 0.

Comment: Don't use `slice` as a variable name: it's a builtin class (that's why the markdown renders it orange).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is laying within the mechanism of numpy slicing and indexing. So first of all this `A[1:2]` returns only one row as the range in exclusive in the end so you need to replace it by `A[1:3]`. Second you need only the items (6, 11) which are in the first column of 2 rows array, so you do `[:, 0]`.
Together => `np.mean(A[1:3][:, 0])`.

Comment: Had to change the data type of the matrix to a Numpy array. Then it worked. Thx

Comment: Oh sorry I missed writing that part :)

Answer (score 1):

As currently written your `A` is a nested list. It is not a numpy array.

If you want to access elements from this list you can simply do indexing.

```
A[1][0]
#6.0

A[2][0]
#11.0

(A[1][0]+A[2][0])/2
#8.5
```

If you convert your list to np.array then:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0],
     [ 6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0, 10.0],
     [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
     [16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]])

A[1:3, 0].mean()
#8.5
```